# How do I put a question mark above \leq?

Tags: latex

How can I put a question mark above a less-than-or-equal-to symbol(`\leq`) in LaTeX?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `stackrel`:

```
\begin{equation}
  2 \stackrel{?}{\le} 3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Or, if you use the `amsmath` package, you can use `overset` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  2 \overset{?}{\le} 3
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 4):

`\stackrel{\text{\tiny ?}}{=}`

Comment: @sgm: Why go into `\text` (`\text` requires `amsmath`, but that's OK since it's used a lot anyway) and change the fontsize rather than use `\scriptscriptstyle` in math mode if you want it small? There may well be a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

Use the accents package.  You can do more fun stuff with TeX primitives, but here's the easy and most flexible way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\qleq}{\accentset{?}{\leq}}
\begin{document}
Test: $a \qleq b$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this one because it does not raise issues when using superscripts, while in the other solutions which were presented here using a superscript would make it such that it would be on the text which is on top of the symbol, rather than staying on the symbol itself.